# Grails: find in hasmany-relation

Tags: grails, groovy, find

I have two Classes in Grails:

```
class Person {
    static hasMany = [tickets: Ticket]
}
```

and

```
class Ticket {
    String ticketStatus
}
```

ticketStatus can be any string that describes the ticket. How can I find all instances of Person that have one ore more tickets with specific status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I find all instances of Person that have one ore more tickets
> with specific status?

A common way is using `DetachedCriteria`:

```
def results = Person.findAll {
    tickets {
        ticketStatus == 'some status you would like to search for'
    }
}
```

Depending on which database and driver you are using you may get different SQL but with H2 this is what that query will generate:

```
select this_.id as id1_0_1_, this_.version as version2_0_1_, tickets3_.person_tickets_id as person_t1_1_, tickets_al1_.id as ticket_i2_1_, tickets_al1_.id as id1_2_0_, tickets_al1_.version as version2_2_0_, tickets_al1_.ticket_status as ticket_s3_2_0_ from person this_ inner join person_ticket tickets3_ on this_.id=tickets3_.person_tickets_id inner join ticket tickets_al1_ on tickets3_.ticket_id=tickets_al1_.id where tickets_al1_.ticket_status=?
```

Comment: I expected it that simple but did not see it! Thank you Jeff!

Comment: "I expected it that simple..." - Indeed.  GORM provides really powerful query mechanisms.  This one is a good example of that.   Good luck!